# Unable to Install Apk with same com.comapanyname

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, package, game-development, failed-installation

I uploaded a game on google playstore with Package name **com.UltraGamingStudio.Protector**. When i tried to build another game with package name **com.UltraGamingStudio.EndlessCrazyBall** it failed to install on my phone if i have com.UltraGamingStudio.Protector installed.

If i uninstall it then i am able to install new. I also build game with com.ultragamingstudio.protector and com.ultragamingstudio.endlesscrazyball but with lowercase letter it also cause problem. This only **solve** if i **change** my **company name**.

I get the following errors on second game build

**Error 1**
**Installation failed with the following output:**
The APKs have been extracted in the directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\2554891050332097196
The APKs have been extracted in the directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\2554891050332097196
[BT:1.6.0] Error: Installation of the app failed.
com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.exceptions.CommandExecutionException: Installation of the app failed.
at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.exceptions.InternalExceptionBuilder.build(InternalExceptionBuilder.java:57)
at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.DdmlibDevice.installApks(DdmlibDevice.java:154)
at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.InstallApksCommand.lambda$execute$1(InstallApksCommand.java:197)
at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.AdbRunner.run(AdbRunner.java:81)
at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.AdbRunner.run(AdbRunner.java:61)
at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.InstallApksCommand.execute(InstallApksCommand.java:196)
at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.BundleToolMain.main(BundleToolMain.java:90)
at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.BundleToolMain.main(BundleToolMain.java:48)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to commit install session 1958722662 with command cmd package install-commit 1958722662. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Scanning Failed.: Can't install because provider name com.UGS.Dragon.Hunting.Game.huawei.mobileadsinitprovider (in package com.ultragamingstudio.endlesscrazyball) is already used by com.ultragamingstudio.protector
at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstallerBase.installCommit(SplitApkInstallerBase.java:99)
at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:85)
at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackages(DeviceImpl.java:1117)
at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.DdmlibDevice.installApks(DdmlibDevice.java:138)
... 6 more
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

**Error 2**
**DeploymentOperationFailedException: Installation failed. See the Console for details.**
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension.UploadAndroidAppBundle (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildProperties buildProperties, UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.IDeploymentTargetsMainThreadContext context, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice device, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+LaunchProgressTaskManager taskManager) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+<>c__DisplayClass12_1.b__1 () (at :0)
UnityEditor.ProgressTaskManager.Run () (at <6a4b923691b54d0eb965a9ed2a807ce9>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension.LaunchBuildOnTarget (UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.IDeploymentTargetsMainThreadContext context, UnityEditor.BuildProperties buildProperties, UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetId targetId, UnityEditor.ProgressHandler progressHandler) (at :0)
UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetManager.LaunchBuildOnTarget (UnityEditor.BuildProperties buildProperties, UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetId targetId, UnityEditor.ProgressHandler progressHandler) (at <6a4b923691b54d0eb965a9ed2a807ce9>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer+<>c__DisplayClass19_1.b__1 () (at <6a4b923691b54d0eb965a9ed2a807ce9>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

**Error 3**
**UnityException: Could not find any valid targets to launch on for Android**
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.LaunchOnTargets (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget buildTarget, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] launchTargets) (at <6a4b923691b54d0eb965a9ed2a807ce9>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Launch (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.LaunchPlayer (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildLaunchPlayerArgs args) (at :0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Launch (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget buildTarget, System.String path, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport) (at <6a4b923691b54d0eb965a9ed2a807ce9>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

**UnityException: Could not find any valid targets to launch on for Android**

But these errors only occures if i have already game installed with same companyname in package name.
from weeks i am trying to solve it.

I use **Admob** and **Unity** ads. i use same admob appID and adsIDs in both games.
Both games are approved on playstore but i can not install both on same device.

Please guide me if the problem can be solved without changing company name.

Comment: We have several apps that all use the same company name. (com.X.A, com.X.b) We do use different settings for ads, analytics, etc. though. You might try that. This `Can't install because provider name com.UGS.Dragon.Hunting.Game.huawei.mobileadsinitprovider (in package com.ultragamingstudio.endlesscrazyball) is already used by com.ultragamingstudio.protector` does seem to point to some sort of conflict in an ad provider.

Comment: @RetiredNinja i am not sure how to fix this issue. Where i can find com.UGS.Dragon.Hunting.Game.huawei.mobileadsinitprovider to change this and how you find it?

Comment: " i use same admob appID and adsIDs in both games" Change them for the new game.

Comment: I change admob appId and adsId but same issue, I delete GoogleMobileAd folder same problem, when I delete android folder in plugins folder then issue resolved. I encountered some issues in android plugins so that instead of resolve dependancies I delete androidx plugins and export package. I use that package for all games may be issue is with plugins. @RetiredNinja Thanks for your help I was thinking that problem is with package name.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have a question if you don't mind.

I use package name com.UGS.Dragon.Hunting.Game.huawei for huawei game which is not live yet. How you find com.UGS.Dragon.Hunting.Game.huawei.mobileadsinitprovider?

Comment: I'm not sure where you would find that. I'd probably start by extracting the apk and looking at the manifest. https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/ You may have a plugin with a prebuild step that's injecting that somehow.